# Plotting with gnuplot from several files

Tags: gnuplot

I have several files called `data_x.dat`, where `x` ranges from `1` to `10`. I'm looking for something in gnuplot that would allow me to directly plot the second column agains the first one of all of the files in the same graph, instead of doing

```
p "data_1.dat" u 1:2, "data_2.dat" u 1:2, ..., "data_10.dat" u 1:2
```

which is slow to type. Something like:

```
p "data_*" u 1:2
```

is what I'm looking for. Does it exist for gnuplot?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inline iterations:

```
plot for [i=1:10] sprintf("data_%d.dat", i) u 1:2
```